# Resnick - Probability Path - Exercise 7.19

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Resnick's book:

> Suppose {$X_n, n\geq 1$} are non-negative independent random variables. Then:
>
> (i) $\sum_n X_n < \infty$ almost surelly iff
>
> (ii) $\sum_n E[\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}]<\infty$ iff
>
> (iii) $\sum_n E[ min(X_n,1)]<\infty$

My approach to the problem was the following:

(i)$\Rightarrow$ (iii):

$\sum_n X_n < \infty$ almost surelly $\Rightarrow$ there exists $n_0$ such that for $n>n_0$ $\sum_{i=n_0}^{\infty}X_i < \epsilon < 1$, $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily close to $0$, which implies also $X_i < 1$ for $i>n_0$.

Thus $\sum_n E[min(X_n,1)] \leq M + \sum_{i=n_0}^{\infty}E(X_i) = M + E(\sum_{i=n_0}^{\infty}X_i) < M+\epsilon < \infty$

(iii)$\Rightarrow$ (ii):

For all n $\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}<1$ and $\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}<X_n$, thus $\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}< min(X_n,1)$

So, by monotony of expectancy, $E[\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}]< E[min(X_n,1)]$ for all n, which implies

$\sum_n E[\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}]< \sum_n E[min(X_n,1)] < \infty$

**Now I got stuck on this part:**

(ii)$\Rightarrow$ (i)

My approach was trying to do:

$\sum_n E[\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}] < \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}E[\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}] = 0$, so that by expectancy monotony and since $\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}>0$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}=1-\frac{1}{1-X_n}=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=0$, which is not enough to guarantee that $\sum_n X_n < \infty$.

Any hints on how to get that $\sum_n X_n < \infty$ almost surelly?

Thanks

Comment: The first argument looks correct to me, although it should be noted that monotone convergence is what allows the interchange of summation and expectation.

Comment: In fact, I can not guarantee that $\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}$ is monotone, but since it is greater then $0$, the only way $\lim_{n\to\infty}E[\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}] = 0$ is if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{1+X_n} = 0$. I don't know if this is the best path to show what I need, that $\sum_n X_n <\infty$, since I got stuck. Do you know any other approach?

Comment: @Math1000 Is the following correct?

$\infty > \sum_n E[\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}] =  E[\sum_n \frac{X_n}{1+X_n}] \geq 
 E[ \frac{\sum_nX_n}{1+\sum_nX_n}] \Rightarrow \sum_n X_n < \infty$,

since if $\sum_n X_n = \infty$, we would have $E(\frac{\infty}{\infty})$ which is indeterminate